# Help me to understand this code

Tags: solidity

I did not understand these code:

```
(uint256(getUserRoles[user]) >> role) & 1 != 0;
```

and

```
require(
            to.code.length == 0 ||
                ERC721TokenReceiver(to).onERC721Received(msg.sender, from, id, "") ==
                ERC721TokenReceiver.onERC721Received.selector,
            "UNSAFE_RECIPIENT"
        );
```

- here what does `to.code.length` mean? `to` is an address here.

Answer (score 0):

The code **uint256(getUserRoles[user]) >> role** is a bit-wise operation that shifts the bits of the **getUserRoles[user]** variable to the right by the value of the role variable. The **& 1** operation then checks whether the resulting bit is 1 or 0. This operation is used to determine whether a user has a specific role, which is represented by a bit in the getUserRoles variable. If the bit is 1, then the user has the role, otherwise, the user does not have the role.

The code **to.code.length** is checking the length of the code at the address to. The **to** variable is expected to be an instance of a smart contract. If **to.code.length** is zero, it means that the contract is not deployed at the provided address, or it does not have any code. In the context of the **require** statement, this check is used to ensure that the **to** address is a valid recipient for an ERC721 token transfer.

The require statement also checks that if the **to** address is a contract, then it implements the **onERC721Received** function of the **ERC721TokenReceiver** interface. The **onERC721Received** function is called by the ERC721 contract when a token is transferred, and it is used to ensure that the recipient can handle the token transfer correctly. The **ERC721TokenReceiver.onERC721Received.selector** is a special function selector that represents the **onERC721Received** function signature. This check is used to ensure that the recipient contract can handle the ERC721 token transfer safely, and prevent the loss of tokens due to contract errors.